# Saving Metadata to DB (QGIS 3.4 or higher)

Tags: database, metadata, save

Is it possible to save metadata of a QGIS 3 layer in a database (PostGIS), similar to the function in QGIS 2.18 "save layer style to database".

I don't want to save it in the project or as a file.

[image: 2.18]

[image: 3.4]

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation states](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#savemetadatatodb) that ‘For PostgreSQL data sources if the [configuration option](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html?highlight=database%20connection#database-related-tools) *Allow saving/loading QGIS layer metadata in the database* is checked the metadata are stored inside a dedicated table in the database.’

It was difficult to get it to work. For my first attempts, I enabled saving metadata in the DB Connection Settings (which I had previously left unchecked), then wrote a short description in the abstract field (*Zusammenfassung* in the OP's localised screenshot) and then tried to save it as default. (*Als Vorgabe* in the screenshot). But when I tried to restore the default (*Vorgabe wiederherstellen*), I just got a ‘Metadata not found in database’ message.

However, at some point it started to work. I noticed that I have a table named *qgis_layer_metadata* in the same DB schema where my data layers are. If you have this table, then it works, or has at least worked at some point in time. (You can of course check the contents of this table to see if any of your metadata edits have been saved.) Note that if you edit the metadata fields, the changes will **not** be saved into the DB unless you click *Metadata* → *Save as Default*.

There seems to have been [a lot](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/25119) [of](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/43054) [related](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/43063) [issues](https://github.com/Ouranosinc/pavics-sdi/issues/234) in GitHub, and some of them requested for extensive design changes, so even though they're all in a closed or merged status by now, I'm still wondering if further changes are on the way.